# SerializedName annotated member is getting obfuscated in release build Android

Tags: android, serialization, retrofit, parcelable, android-annotations

In recent release build creation, one of my classes which had @SerializedName member was getting obfuscated, which didn't happen in previous release.

My class:

```
data class Segments(
        @SerializedName("list")
        val list: List<Segment>
)
```

Using `-keepattributes *Annotation*` also in proguard.

Please can anybody help me, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent lot of time figuring out why my other class members are not obfuscated and not getting any null pointer crash.

Firstly **Invalidate cache and restart** mostly it will be caching issue.if not working try below solution.

(My assumption is *Proguard/R8 is messing up* this). I know I can use @Keep but I don't wanted to do that, as it was **@SerializedName** Annotation. Later found the fix,

1. Initialised data member
2. Annotated with @Parcelize and implemented Parcelable,

   ```
    @Parcelize
    data class Segments(
        @SerializedName("list")
        val segments: List<HomeFSegmentsSegment> = ArrayList()
    ) : Parcelable
   ```

This may/may not be exact solution to the problem, but it did solve the issue.